# Splitting large data file in python

Tags: python, excel, large-data, large-data-volumes, data-management

I output a large array into a text file in python. I then read it in excel to plot the data.
Currently, the file I am writing is too large to read in excel.

I use file open and close functions and write the data in array ( please refer the code):

```py
with open("abc.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(abc_value))
    file.close()
```

Question: How can I split the data file so that after 1000000 steps (approximately), the file closes and starts writing to another file.

At the end, there should be multiple data files which I can read in excel separately.

Any leads much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is type(abc_value) originally, but if you can submit in in a form of array this code should work:

```
counter = 1
for i in range(0, len(abc_value), 1000000):
    with open(f"abc{counter}.txt", "w") as file:
        for val in abc_value[i:i + 1000000]:
            file.write(str(val))
        file.close()
        counter += 1
```

The main idea is just to split your original data and then create and open deferent files in for loop.

Output files should be "abc1.txt","abc2.txt",...

Hope I understood your question correctly and this answers it.

Comment: Thank you very much! To answer your question, abc_value is an array.